# Runners cannot pull from private gitlab container registry

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

Tried to update our infra to use our pipeline images from self-hosted GitLab using Container Registry (prev. using DO's Container Registry, all working).

The pipeline image is in a separate repo on the same GitLab instance and pushed to the Container Registry.

The application's pipeline sometimes fails with a permission error that it cannot pull the image. Which is weird as if I restart the pipeline it works and can pull the image. I'm not using any env like `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` as from the docs it should be able to access images from the private project's container registry. Also, it always works on master branch.

If the image is pulled, it usually works around 1-2 hours then it starts to fail.

We are using auto-scaled workers if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was a syntax error in config.toml. Gitlab runner did not throw any error just randomly failing to load it.